# Cannot find string in table matlab

Tags: matlab

Writing in Matlab
I am trying to find this string "+972 52-697-8081" in a the table namesnumbers as can be seen in the picture,it exists in the table though it returns 0 in the specific place where it exists.the line i used is

```
    IndexC = strfind(namesnumbers{:,:},string(newnum)  );
```

When i tried contains not a variable it did find the index though as a specific number

```
   IndexC = strfind(namesnumbers{:,:},"+972 52-697-8081" );
```

What am I doing wrong?
link to the excel
sheets:https://www.transfernow.net/dl/202107194gVG4laZ/ej6NSpdd

[image]
the code:

```
finalnames=readtable("names1example.xlsx");
     m1="101.xlsx";    
     t=readtable(m1);
     m=t(4:end,:);
     
    [size1,~]=size(t);
 
    numbers=t(:,3);
    namesnumbers=finalnames(:,3);
    for k=3:size1
       number= numbers{k,1};
   
     IndexC = strfind(namesnumbers{:,:},string(number)  );
    
    Index = find(not(cellfun('isempty',IndexC)));
    gender=finalnames(Index,2);
    name=finalnames(Index,1);
       end
    
     
    t(:,4)= (name);
    
    t(:,5)= (gender);
    t(:,6:end)=m;
    m2=append("H",m1);
    writetable(t,m2);
```

Comment: Your code cannot run without the excel file. Please remove the irrelevant part and create a [mre]

Comment: Your code doesn't match from top to bottom and the posted snippet is incomplete.

Comment: @Matt thanks i updated accordingly

Comment: link to the excel sheets:https://www.transfernow.net/dl/202107194gVG4laZ/ej6NSpdd

Comment: You could just copy and paste a couple of rows of the original sheet, you know. We really don't need all of your data to make it work (or fail).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `strfind` with tables for what you're trying to do.

The quick example bellow should give you an indication how to extract a single or multiple rows from your table.

```
% example table from MATLAB doc
T = table(categorical({'M';'F';'M'}),[45;32;34],...
          {'NY';'CA';'MA'},logical([1;0;0]),...
          'VariableNames',{'Gender','Age','State','Vote'})

% get the row that matches the string "NY"
T(T.State == "NY",:)

% get the rows where the state matches any of the given set
setOfStates = ["NY", "CA", "CAN"];
T(ismember(T.State,setOfStates),:)
```